# Regex JavaScript expect string double quote

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex  : `(config\.[\w]*)`

My test string:

```
config.giauht + "config.giauht" config.giauht config.new config.
config config.abc newconfig.
```

My jsfildde: [Link](https://regex101.com/r/nK0oV6/2)

I want output result not include value in **double quote**:

```
"config.giauht"
**config.giauht** + "config.giauht" **config.giauht** **config.new** **config.**
config **config.abc** newconfig.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If quotes are all balanced you can try this regex:

```
/\bconfig\.\w*(?!\S*")/
```

`(?!\S*")` is negative lookahead to fail the match if `"` is the next character after 0 or more non-space characters in your pattern.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK0oV6/6)

Comment: your result lost  'config.', i need config.

Comment: I am using Mobile so can check demo site. But you can probably try `/\bconfig\.((?!\w)|\w+\b(?!"))/`

Comment: i don't need "config." , only config.

Comment: @GiauHuynh: Check updated answer now. It is matching `config.` but won't match `"config."` or `"config.giauht"`

Comment: @Mariano: Yes that will work for opening quote but will also include preceding non-`"` character in match.

Answer (score 1):

```
(config\.[\w]*)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can try this.This will not give values inside `quotes.`See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/3

Comment: your regex not match my test string

Comment: @GiauHuynh did you see the demo.What's d mismatch der

Comment: thanks vks, but your regex get more step to find result than anubhava, not good performance!